# Datagridview [isn't a valid sort string entry]?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a form that contains a datagridview, I'm binding this dataGridView to DB, I'm using a function Bind(string sqlQuery) and when i call this line, the datagridView is filled with data :

```
Bind("SELECT title,description,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) > 0 THEN CONCAT('Dans ',DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()), ' Jours') WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) = 0 THEN CONCAT('Demain') ELSE CONCAT('Expiré depuis ', DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) * -1, ' Jours') END),progress FROM taches WHERE 1");
```

The data is correctly filled in the dataGridView :

**The problem** : When i click on the each columnHeader the data is sorted (by ascending or descending) except when I click on the column header `deadline`, the application stops working and I get an Exception says the following :

`[(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline isn't a valid Sort string entry`

How can I make the column sortable when I click on it or at least how to avoid this exception from being thrown !

The different values that can be contained in the column "deadline" are the following :

`Dans X Jours`
`Expiré depuis X Jours`
`Demain`

Where `Dans X Jours` > `Demain` > `Expiré depuis X Jours`

X is an number that represent the number of days !

How to make this column sortable without getting exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following (I'm not formatting for the sake of copy / paste easiness):

```
Bind("SELECT title,description,(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) > 0 THEN CONCAT('Dans ',DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()), ' Jours') WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) = 0 THEN CONCAT('Demain') ELSE CONCAT('Expiré depuis ', DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) * -1, ' Jours') END) as deadline,progress FROM taches WHERE 1");
```

In the SQL query, you have to specify the column name for the `deadline` column (below is the formatted query):

```
SELECT 
  title,
  description,
  (CASE 
      WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) > 0 
         THEN CONCAT('Dans ',DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()), ' Jours') 
      WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) = 0 
         THEN CONCAT('Demain') 
       ELSE CONCAT('Expiré depuis ', DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) * -1, ' Jours') 
    END) as deadline,
  progress 
FROM 
  taches 
WHERE 1
```